# Issues with Java code formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, format

I develop Java in vscode + some java extensions (one of them is Red Hat's Java support).
When I last checked in the code, I believe that Red Hat's ext attempted to format the code in some files, which made my boss furious.

If I set the java.format.enabled to off, it should not happen again, should it? I want to be able to preserve the code in whichever shape and style it was there prior to my changes.

I otherwise love working with vscode, but don't want to get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

yea, it can be.
"java.format.enabled": false,
can do it.